# EF Core Scaffolding with Oracle Autonomous Database

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Curious if anyone has successfully done database scaffolding for EF Core with Oracle Cloud's Autonomous Database offering (*not* an on-premises Oracle DB). The tricky part seems to be the connection string. ADB requires now use of a wallet download, and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Oracle's [ODP.Net example](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/samples/dotnet-core/autonomous-db/autonomous-odp-core.cs) shows some special configuration commands to configure the data provider. But, these commands seem not to be available when using Scaffold-DbContext. The idea of placing the needed files in the same location as the data connection library sounds great, except NuGet libraries seem not to be persisted and are only deployed as part of the build process. Their [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases) on connecting to ADB suggests rewriting the connection string to use the Easy Connect format which seems not to be supported.

They've an unrelated post on [connecting SSRS to ADB](https://www.oracle.com/a/otn/docs/database/connecting-ssrs-to-oracle-adb.pdf) that has some command line configuration for a data provider that I haven't tried yet because I'm not sure if it would work, but seems like it may potentially be useful at least in figuring out some sort of solution.

.NET Core/EF Core versions are 3.1.9.

A few variations I've tried...(with {} indicating placeholders for redacted information)

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id={uname};Password={pwd};
Data Source={(description...) from tnsnames.ora}" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

*result*: request times out

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id={uname};Password={pwd};
Data Source={tcps://... from blog}" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

*result*: invalid connection string

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id={uname};Password={pwd};
Data Source={host}:{port}/{service_name}" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

*result*: Failed to connect to server

If anyone has any wisdom to share on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: are you able to connect from Visual Studio?

Comment: I am -- I'm using Rider now, but it's able to connect with the appropriate JDBC driver.

Comment: Then you should be able to reuse the connection string?

Comment: Sadly no because the .NET Core drivers don't support the same syntax as the JDBC thin drivers, but I was finally able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

1. Copy wallet.sso, sqlnet.ora, and tnsnames.ora to your project root directory
2. Obtain the data source name from tnsnames.ora--you will typically see three options, one for {dbname}_high, one for {dbname}_low, one for {dbname}_medium. Refer to Oracle's documentation on the difference between them, but _high worked fine for me.
3. Execute your scaffolding command. Shown below is a basic example using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` with a dbname of TEST, user id of ADMIN, and password of PASSWORD

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=TEST_high;User Id=ADMIN;Password=PASSWORD" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

4. Probably need to modify `OnConfiguring` of the created DataContext...will update when I get a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to not use Wallets.

There is, in this link [oracle autonomous database without wallet using TLS](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/securely-connecting-to-autonomous-db-without-a-wallet-using-tls.), a to-do to change Autonomous Database to use TLS insteado mTLS and wallets.

After changing the database, just use

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(description...);User Id=ADMIN;Password=PASSWORD" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```